# Get New Back UIBarButtonItem iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have an app that I am writing for iOS 7. I am using navigation bars and I want a nice looking back button. I noticed that on the navigation bar in the objects menu there is a nice looking back button: 
[image: Navigation Bar in Objects Menu]

However when I add a UIBarButtonItem I cannot find it under the list of button identifiers:
[image: List of identifiers]

How can I get this new sexy (for lack of a better word) back button? Why would Xcode have that under a navigation controller but not have it as an actual button?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting a back button in a place other than when a back button is automatically added by the UINavigationController?

Comment: @random I am not using a UINavigationController. So yes.

Comment: What are you trying to use it in? A UITabBar? UIToolBar? UINavigationBar you added yourself in a xib? A UIButton?

Comment: @random A UINavigationBar I added myself in a .xib with a UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BackButton"];

[self.myNavBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:YES];
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this in interface builder?

Comment: @cabellicar123 Nope, no way to do it in interface builder.